# Tensorflow Serving Developer environment

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I can't seem to find any documentation that describes what parts of TF and TFS need to be installesd/built to create a servable, can anyone shed light on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this documentation exists. The approach I would take is to create a new blank environment, on conda or whatever you prefer. Then install Tensorflow and Tensorflow serving into the environment, which will prompt you to install the dependencies into the environment as well.

Then just to pip list or conda list (or equivalent) and see what all libraries got installed. That should give you a list of the base libraries needed to use TF and TF Serving.

Comment: I am working in a C++/CMake environment and I am most waylayed on the problem of setting up the build environment to correctly compile required protobuf files in their correct order for TF Serving clients.